# Unity Animation OnStateExit doesn't work when i add conditions

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, animator

I am trying to get OnStateExit when animation is finished.Actually it is working but without conditions.

I am triggering to start other animation when drop animation finished.OnStateExit's job is trigger the other animation but when i add conditions OnStateExit doesn't triggering

These are picture from Animator. As you see in two pictures where are in bottom.

[image]
.

.

There is no conditions on Drop animation and It is WORKING

[image]

.

.

When i add condition to the Drop anim it is NOT WORKING. As you see in picture i am addding condition to arrow

[image]

.

.

What is the problem? I didn't understand.

Comment: What do you mean by not working?  Is Drop set to Loop, etc?  What is that Animator Trigger script? etc.

Comment: @jiveturkey I am triggering to start other animation when drop animation finished.OnStateExit's job is trigger the other animation but when i add conditions OnStateExit doesn't triggering.

Comment: I tried other OnState Triggers and i saw other OnState Triggers is working like Update , Enter etc.Probably this problem's reason is OnStateExit doesn't working when arrow is doesn't working